# MS Access Linked Table Permissions

Tags: ms-access, permissions

Does anyone know which permissions are required for refreshing or connecting to linked tables in ms access 2003?

I have basically two user level security groups setup; 1 for admins and 1 user level.  Admins have full permissions and have no trouble refreshing the linked tables.   The users group has read/update/delete permissions for the data and open/run permissions for the macro's forms and reports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I should just read the MS Access help files first ;)

In general, if you want users to be able to access a linked table (linked table: A table stored in a file outside the open database from which Access can access records. You can add, delete, and edit records in a linked table, but you cannot change its structure.), grant them Read Data and Read Design permissions on the table in the back-end database, and Modify Design permission on the table link defined in the front-end database so that they can conveniently re-link the table. If you want to restrict all access to the back-end table but still allow users to view the data and re-link the tables, remove all permissions on the back-end table and use queries in the front-end database with their RunPermissions property set to Owner's.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to refresh or connect to access linked tables via VBA, there is a VBA add-in you can download from -> [Access Linked Table VBA add-in](http://www.access-linked-table.com/)

This allows you or your users to link whenever you need them to, and if necessary to multiple databases

Comment: There's probably at least 100 instances of Access table relinking code out there on the Internet. My own, http://dfenton.com/DFA/download/Access/Reconnect.html , makes it easy to relink to multiple back ends, for instance.